# What does newArray = myNumpyArray[:,0] mean?

Tags: python, numpy

Not too familiar with Python and need to translate some code. Here is the gist of what I am having a problem with:

```
import numpy
myNumpyArray = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
newArray = myNumpyArray[:,0]
```

I don't know what `myNumpyArray[:,0]` means and get compile error `IndexError: too many indices`.

Comment: If you don't know what `myNumpyArray[:,0]` means, why did you do it?

Comment: I didn't do it. I am translating an algorithm from python to swift and someone else who I can't talk to wrote that line. Thanks for the down vote.

Comment: `myNumpyArray[:,0]` means selecting the first element along the second axis. Thus, to make it work you need an array that has at least two dimensions. In your case, `myNumpyArray` is a 1D array.

Comment: You should first learn about [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myNumpyArray[:,0]
```

means the first column of myNumpyArray, since your array is 1-Dimensional, this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. In my example I just used a one d array. The actual code is way more complicated so now I get it.